# Best free library for OCR in ios

Tags: ios, ocr

i want to get the text info from the image. and i have tried Tesseract library for implement OCR. but i am not getting the best result from this library. please suggest more solution for OCR scanning text in iphone/objective c. i required new and updated free framework with max accuracy in text recognition.

please suggest me .
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Tessetact is great. If you were not having desired results, you probably should train it more and adjust to your needs. From the free ones, I doubt you'll find anything better.

Comment: Thanks @Fengson for suggest , but when i click image from camera and recognition text with the help of Tessetact  library i am not getting accrate text in response, while when i put one .png file and then scan this image will get most accurate text from image. so please suggest

Comment: You need to train Tesseract and adjust dictionary and/or fonts for him to be able to scan more precisely.

Comment: Ok Thanks Fengson , i will try me best

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You should try this library, it supports objective-c and swift both

https://github.com/gali8/Tesseract-OCR-iOS

Comment: Awesome! But he already failed with Tesseract.

Comment: How is this accpted answer? He said he tried Tesseract, and now you're suggesting the same...

Comment: @Fengson I think he used another tesseract library instead of this. I have used this library. It works for me

Comment: @User7219949 am also trying to implement this. but unable to get exact output. could you share sample code how to work with this